# Export 2 tables in the same sheet and excel file ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I need to export 2 excel tables in the same excel file and the same excel sheet using angular ag-grid.

Currently I export them in the same document but on different sheets

```
var spreadsheets = [];

spreadsheets.push(
  this.degradeTable.api?.getSheetDataForExcel()!,
  this.benchmarkTable.api?.getSheetDataForExcel()!
);

exportMultipleSheetsAsExcel({
  data: spreadsheets,
  fileName: 'ag-grid.xlsx',
});
```

Thank you very much for the help